Deserialize and process only certain fields, but retain the rest
A component in a messaging system should only work on certain properties of each message and be indifferent about the other ones. Messages are being passed in the XML format. Using the Jackson library, how can I deserialize a message so that the relevant components can be used, but all other properties are being retained so that when the object gets serialized and passed to the next component, no information is lost?
An example: Let's say that this is the XML message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyMessage>
  <RelProperty>This is the property used by the current component</RelProperty>
  <IrrelProperty1>This is something irrelevant for the current component</IrrelProperty1>
  <IrrelProperty2 value="This is another relevant property" />
</MyMessage>

The according data class in the component could be:
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="MyMessage")
data class MyMessage(
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="RelProperty")
  var text: String = ""

  // do not model irrelevant properties here
)

Since the component only works on (an possibly modifies) the RelProperty, it should only deserialize that field. However, after processing the message it has to be serialized again to be passed to the next component. Here, all other properties should be kept the way they were received. Is there a way to implement this with the Jackson library wihtput having to map the entire message dataformat in each component?
